# How to measure leakage current through a capacitor in a simulation?

Tags: capacitor, simulation, leakage-current

I am trying to design a new capacitor and then measure the leakage current through it. First, I want to find a way to measure the leakage current through a capacitor. I am using a PDK which has real capacitor models and a plot of the leakage current. I want to see if I can design a test circuit to the plot.

The plot of the leakage current is shown below. The documentation does not really mention that \$I_j\$ and \$V_j\$ are. The circuit I'm using to simulate measure the leakage is shown below. Since I don't know where \$V_j\$ is, I assumed it is the third terminal of the capacitor. I connected the first 2 terminals of the capacitor the usual way to charge the capacitor and then swept the third terminal to see if I can measure some current through the capacitor. The simulation shows 0 current. I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas how to correctly measure the leakage current?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In your simulation did you see zero current at V1 or at V0? Did you look at the tabular results or just a graph?

Comment: This documentation that mentions Vj ... a link to it might be useful. (capacitors don't usually have a third terminal, I would expect leakage to be between the usual two)

Comment: The third terminal could be voltage from other material on the side of the capacitor. Check the model of the three terminal cap for more information. It would be great if you could also post what model you are using for the cap or the name of the model

Comment: @ThePhoton, I actually plotted the current in every branch, measured 0 in all.

Comment: @user_1818839, this is an on-chip capacitor. The third terminal is connected to the p sub.

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I am using a MIM capacitor from the 22nm FD-SOI pdk. The third terminal connects to p sub. I simply want to see if I can replicate the results (current leakage) from the PDK manual (which is proprietary).

Comment: @LeonhardEuler Please put ALL available information in your question. Both info from comments above and anything else relevaqnt and useful.

Comment: The simulation shows 0 current where? Did you actually measure the current through the vsource you placed at the psub connection? Can you also measure the current flowing out of the bottom node of the cap?